# How to use alias in where clause laravel elequent with postgres

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

This is my query

```
Student::query()
    ->addSelect(['presentCount' =>
        Score::query()
            ->selectRaw('count(*)')
            ->whereColumn('student_id', '=', 'students.id')
            ->where('created_at', '>', getBeginningOfThisYear())
            ->where('presence', '=', 1)
    ])->where('presentCount', '>=', 5)->get()
```

the raw SQL is

```
select "students".*, (select count(*) from "scores" where "student_id" = "students"."id" and "created_at" > ? and "presence" = ? and "scores"."deleted_at" is null) as "presentCount" from "students" where "presentCount" >= ? and "students"."deleted_at" is null
```

the problem is **presentCount** is an alias and it can not be used in where clause, however if I can change the SQL  to be like:

```
select * from (select "students".*, (select count(*) from "scores" where "student_id" = "students"."id" and "created_at" > ? and "presence" = ? and "scores"."deleted_at" is null) as "presentCount" from "students" ) as students where "students"."presentCount" >= ? and "students"."deleted_at" is null
```

The question is how can I transform the query using query builder not raw SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
Student::query()->from(fn($q) => $q->from('students')->addSelect(['presentCount' =>
            Score::query()
                ->selectRaw('count(*)')
                ->whereColumn('student_id', '=', 'students.id')
                ->where('created_at', '>', getBeginningOfThisYear())
                ->where('presence', '=', 1)
        ]), 'students')->where('presentCount', '>', 5)->get()
```

will generate:

```
select * from (select "students".*, (select count(*) from "scores" where "student_id" = "students"."id" and "created_at" > ? and "presence" = ? and "scores"."deleted_at" is null) as "presentCount" from "students") as "students" where "presentCount" > ? and "students"."deleted_at" is null
```

#### and it works correctly.